# Need some advice with an Shoutcast app using intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

I'm trying to develop an app that will just stream a shoutcast, the deal is I can't make it work, I'm testing my app on a android 4.2 and it seems to not work at all, I'm just doing the example from intel xdk documentation.

Here is the simple code i have made atm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your New Application</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<style type="text/css">
    *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
    input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
    body { background-color:white; color:black }
</style>
<script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onDeviceReady=function(){



    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);


    function PlayMe() {
        intel.xdk.player.startShoutcast("http://209.9.238.10:8008/",true);

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="PlayMe();">PLAY ME</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyone? i really need help with this app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is only seen on Android devices with version 3.0 and above. With the change of the Android web browser and WebView's rendering engine to Webkit, the intel.xdk.startShoutcast() can not successfully executed since it is an internal modification to the browser's engine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this format, it will just stream a shoutcast without errors,
Here is the simple format I have made:

http://209.9.238.10:8008/;strem.mp3

I have tested my app on an android 4.3 and it seems to  work well.